# How to stop the cycle after mistake

Tags: c++

I want to do only the one thing in that cycle ... - the IF or the ELSE .. (when its true and false ofc as you know it ..) If i have two typed students with their information and my first student in group 1 is not with an excellent grade and the second one student is with excellent grade my program prints:
1)first loop on for:it;s false so it makes the else 
2)second loop on for: it's true so it makes the if

and i have:
No information
Student with excellent grade...

I want to see only the students with excellent grade (if i use BREAK; i will stop the FOR cycle) Here is my code:

```
int gr;
cout<<"Enter group that you want to check: ";cin>>gr;
cout<<"Students with excellent grade in group "<<gr<<":\n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(m[i][2]==gr && m[i][3]>=5.500)
            {
                for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                    cout<<setprecision(8)<<m[i][j]<<"\t";
            }
            else
                    cout<<"No students with excellent grade in this group"<<endl;

        }
```

I have the same problem here. Can i use the "bool" type and how in that code(code is based on struct):

```
int x;
bool no_info=false;
p: cout<<"| What personal id you want to search for: ";cin>>x;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  if(pov[i].id==x)
  {
    no_info=true;
    cout<<pov[i].id<<endl;
    cout<<pov[i].name<<endl;
    cout<<pov[i].lastname<<endl;
    cout<<pov[i].department<<endl;
    cout<<pov[i].salary<<endl;
  }
}
  if(no_info){
   cout<<"No information"<<endl;}
 goto p;
```

**EDITED!!!**

Comment: So you know, the homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: Create an array outside the loop. Inside the loop when you find a student store it in the array.  After the loop, you now have all the students you want in the array.

Comment: sorry about homework tag, and peacemaker i thought about that but ... can't i make it with something else :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. But I think what you want is:

```
int gr;
bool no_excellents = true;
cout<<"Enter group that you want to check: ";cin>>gr;
cout<<"Students with excellent grade in group "<<gr<<":\n";
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(m[i][2]==gr && m[i][3]>=5.500)
    {
       no_excellents = false;
       for(j=0;j<4;j++)
           cout<<setprecision(8)<<m[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
}

if(no_excellents)
{
    cout<<"No students with excellent grade in this group"<<endl;
}
```

This will not stop your `for` loop, and will only print those students who have excellent grades. If nobody has excellent grades, the program will tell you so.

Comment: yes but it wont show me if in that group are not students with excellent grade

Comment: @ Koleto: You want to display two lists? Those who have excellent grades, and those who don't?

Comment: I want to display only excellent grades, the problem is that when I have for example 3 students (the "n" is number of students) and i have only one with excellent grade in that group - the program fills up the another two places with no information. 
And Dinkelk i need when i dont have students with excellent grade in that group to say it.

Comment: Actually it works but if i dont have students with excellent grade i can't say it..

Comment: Dinkelk can you check the edited question please to see if you can help me on that code too (its the same problem but i have struct there) i tried to use somekind of bool type but it doesnt work

Comment: @Koleto I think you switched your `true` and `false`. Declare as `true` at the top, set as `false` inside your `if` statement.

Comment: @Koleto also, don't you want to `cin` to variable `x`, not `id`?

Comment: yes yes "x" my bad, and it doesn't work with switched places... it must be something else(maybe the bool type inside this for must be somewhere else, because in first code i had two fors.. or idk) i tried a lot of combinations but it doesn't work, can you check it please

Comment: @Koleto You should open up a new question for this problem. Although related, it obviously doesn't benefit from the same answer.

Comment: i posted it you can check it